# Adding record in MySQL using forward engineering and there was an error for inserting in Numeric Data Type

Tags: mysql, sql

First lets see how my table structure is set:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RFVPOS`.`Station` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `safeDropAmount` DECIMAL(4,4) NOT NULL,
      `deadStockVolume` DECIMAL(4,4) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

And here is what MySQL forward engineering does:

```
   `INSERT INTO `rfvpos`.`station` (`code`, `name`, `safeDropAmount`, `deadStockVolume`) VALUES ('test', 'test',` '100', '300');
```

Im aware that by enclosing my safeDropAmount and deadStockVolume with single qoutes would mean they are in a varchar datatype, so im removing them like this:

```
   `INSERT INTO `rfvpos`.`station` (`code`, `name`, `safeDropAmount`, `deadStockVolume`) VALUES ('test', 'test', 100, 300);
```

But either ways, when i execute these scripts they say the same thing. this:

```
ERROR 1264: 1264: Out of range value for column 'safeDropAmount' at row 1
```

Kindly help me. I was using MySQL before, and after 3 years i'm back again at it, so i'm kinda refreshing.

Best regards,

Comment: change ('test', 'test',` 100, 300); to ('test', 'test',100, 300); and it should work

Comment: @Satya: Good catch. That spurious backtick is a problem, but it would give a different error than the one reported.

Comment: yep. that was unintended. i would edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column datatype `DECIMAL(4,4)` won't allow for a value larger than 0.9999 to be stored. Attempting to store value greater than that (for example, 300) would give the "out of range" error.

`DECIMAL(4,4)` specifies a total of four digits, with four of them (all of them) after the decimal point, leaving zero digits before the decimal point.

If we want to allow values up to 9999.9999, we'd want datatype `DECIMAL(8,4)`.

That's a total of eight digits, with four of those digits after the decimal point, the remainder (8-4) before the decimal point.

---

Also, MySQL will evaluate the values in single quotes as numeric, in a numeric context, such as inserting into DECIMAL column. The addition or removal of the single quotes around the numeric values, e.g. `300` or `'300'`, has no effect, and they will be evaluated the same. (The difference is what error is returned, if we have a value that isn't numeric (invalid column vs .re is a difference in the error returned  what we specify as a literal is not a numeric...  `foo` would raise "Unknown column" error, `'foo'` would raise "Incorrect value" error.

Comment: I found this site:
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.php

And going over the Float type discussion there was this segment telling:
*For example, a column defined as FLOAT(8,5) will look like -999.99999. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001. *

This just means that my declaration Numeric(4,4) means there is a max digit of 4 characters only including decimal and the whole numbers.

But wouldnt this mean, it would still allow an entry from .0001 to 9999?

Comment: from my understanding in this answer, MySQL determines first the max value from the decimal places placed in the parameter of Decimal? 4 means .9999 and that would get all the allocations placed in the first parameter. was that right?

Comment: @LeeJeong: Yes. `DECIMAL(4,0)` gets us four digits before the decimal point. If we wanted four digits before the decimal point and one after, we'd need to use `DECIMAL(5,1)`.

Comment: @LeeJeong: There is a **big** difference between IEEE floating point datatypes (`FLOAT`,`DOUBLE`) and fixed decimal datatypes (`DECIMAL`,`NUMERIC`). And MySQL adds some non-standard extensions to the floating point datatypes.